# ASM call conventions

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, x86, x86-64

I have been reading about calling conventions in ASM and this is what I got so far:

```
          x86(userland)    x86(kernel)    x64(userland)    x64(kernel)

1st arg           Stack           EBX               RDI            RDI
2nd arg           Stack           ECX               RSI            RSI
3rd arg           Stack           EDX               RDX            RDX
4th arg           Stack           ESI               RCX            R10
5th arg           Stack           EDI               R8             R8
6th arg           Stack           EBP               R9             R9

result            EAX             EAX               RAX            RAX
```

My questions are:

1. Is what I have learned so far correct?
2. How can I pass more than 6 arguments in x86(kernel) and x64(both)? Using the stack? Mind to show me a small example?
3. I have a kernel module and I'm willing to call a function in that module from ASM. What convention should I use? kernel or userland?

Comment: My understanding is that the fourth column (labeled "x64(kernel)") is used in the `syscall` interface between user and the kernel.  For calls between functions within the kernel the standard ABI is used (as labeled "x64(userland)"). However, I'm not an expert on this, so someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: For some special cases, research __syscall

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: could you elaborate?

Comment: At least on FreeBSD/x86, one must use __Syscall if one of the arguments is 64-bit. (read: off_t, so mmap, lseek,ftruncate). Pipe also has special semantics, and (on Linux) clone is also funky

Answer (score 4):

1) Yes, it seems to but only for Linux. I think you can rely on the Linux conventions described here: http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf. But actually you are free to pass arguments the way it is described in the [intel assembly manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.pdf) chapter 6.3.3

2) Using the stack is the way the compiler does it:

```
int func(int i, int j, int k, int l, int m, int n, int o, int p, int q) { return q; }
void func2() { func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9); }
```

Then:

```
$ gcc -c func.c && objdump -d func.o
```

Which outputs on my x86_64 machine:

```
0000000000000000 <func>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   7:   89 75 f8                mov    %esi,-0x8(%rbp)
   a:   89 55 f4                mov    %edx,-0xc(%rbp)
   d:   89 4d f0                mov    %ecx,-0x10(%rbp)
  10:   44 89 45 ec             mov    %r8d,-0x14(%rbp)
  14:   44 89 4d e8             mov    %r9d,-0x18(%rbp)
  18:   8b 45 20                mov    0x20(%rbp),%eax
  1b:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  1c:   c3                      retq   

000000000000001d <func2>:
  1d:   55                      push   %rbp
  1e:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  21:   48 83 ec 18             sub    $0x18,%rsp
  25:   c7 44 24 10 09 00 00    movl   $0x9,0x10(%rsp)
  2c:   00 
  2d:   c7 44 24 08 08 00 00    movl   $0x8,0x8(%rsp)
  34:   00 
  35:   c7 04 24 07 00 00 00    movl   $0x7,(%rsp)
  3c:   41 b9 06 00 00 00       mov    $0x6,%r9d
  42:   41 b8 05 00 00 00       mov    $0x5,%r8d
  48:   b9 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%ecx
  4d:   ba 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%edx
  52:   be 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%esi
  57:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  5c:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  61 <func2+0x44>
  61:   c9                      leaveq 
  62:   c3                      retq
```

3) I would say kernel since you're calling the function inside a kernel module. To have a full valid example, you could call your function from C in your module and disassembly the .ko the same way I did to see how the compiler handles it. It should be straight forward.

Comment: I would up-vote a few times your answer if I could :)

Comment: Humm... I have a question. How is that ```callq 61 <func2+0x44>``` is dumper as ```e8 00 00 00 00```? I mean, ```e8``` does mean ```call```, but where is the ```61 <func2+0x44>``` comming from?

Comment: In this case, objdump is run on a binary object so the compiler is not aware about the final virtual address of func1. It will be resolved during the linking process. In this case, it is filled with 0 until then. So objdump just shows you callq 61, 61 referring the next instruction. This has nothing to do with the generated binary (try with hexdump). However if you  run objdump -d on the final a.out, you will notice the actual virtual address of func1 instead of 0.
It may be more interesting in your case to show the assembly code that gcc builds by running gcc -S func.c && cat func.s

Comment: Disabling optimization makes the asm output pretty noisy.  Most of the instructions in `fun` are spilling incoming register args to local stack memory (in the red zone), before eventually returning the one stack arg (above RSP).  Would be clearer if it was *just* that.

Answer (score 2):

I only code for x86, and can give you some feedback for that architecture (the first two columns).

As to 3., if it's a kernel function (as opposed to, say, a libc function), you would use the kernel conventions (your column 2).

As to 1., correct, except that you wouldn't use ebx for the 6th argument. The traditional function prologue would push this argument assuming it were the actual ebp. So the cutoff is actually 5 arguments.

As to 2., if you have more than 5 arguments, you would store them consecutively in memory, and hand on a pointer to the beginning of this memory region in ebx.

Answer (score 1):

As for the kernel calling convention, it uses registers for eficiency. Besides, a syscall is a special call that needs a priviledge level change, and calls that need a priviledge level change use a different stack, so the usual function prolog (`push ebp`, `mov ebp,esp`, etc.) is useless because `ebp` couldn't access any user parameter.

A kernel function might peek the user stack to take the arguments it needs, but for some architectures, accessing user memory from kernel code is not as straight, or easy, or fast as it is in x86, and Linux is meant to be portable to many architectures. So registers, while they are somewhat limited in x86 architecture, is a convenient and fast method to pass arguments. If a syscall would need more than six arguments, one of them would be a pointer to a `struct` held in user memory. The kernel would use the `copy_from_user()` function to copy the structure into kernel memory, if needed (as it is usually done with `ioctl()` syscall, for example).

Comment: I'll be running that ASM code from inside my kernel module, so the code will already have priviledges.

Comment: Then, afaik, you'll be using the standard C calling convention: parameters pushed onto the stack, from right to left. That's how functions inside kernel modules are defined.

Comment: so I'll just ```push``` all my addresses to variables from right to left, then ```call myfunc``` and then ```pop``` whenever I need to get some variable, right?

Comment: Right, but you don't know for sure till you triy. You can always compile a kernel module with -S option and see what kind of assembler code it has generated, so you can be sure of how functions are dealt inside kernel code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps but check out Table 4 and Table 5 in Agner Fog's [Calling conventions for different C++ compilers and operating systems](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf).  These give a nice summary of register usage and calling conventions for C++ different compilers and operating systems.

For x86-64: Windows and Linux only have one calling convention but they are different.  Windows uses 6 registers and Linux 14 registers.

For x86: Windows and Linux use the same calling conventions, however, there are several calling conventions: `cdecl, stdcall, pascal and fastcall`.  The conventions `cdecl, stdcall, and pascal` only use the stack while `fastcall` uses 2 (or three depending on the compiler) integer registers.  The convention `cdecl` is the default.

Windows and Linux also have some different return registers.  You have only list `EAX` and `RAX` but there is also e.g. `XMM0` or `YMMO` or `ST(0)`,...

These results are similar to what you have written for ASM.